# Objects disappearing in NSMutableArray used for view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, nsarray

So I have a view-based NSTableView connected to an array. The table view originally has 2 items, however when I try to add an object using an IBAction, the object somehow disappears during the last iteration of `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` when the table view asks for the view of that row. The code following:

```
-(IBAction)addTask:(id)sender
{
    NSString *task = @"New";

    [todaysTasks addObject:task];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return todaysTasks.count;
}

-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    NSLog (@"%@", todaysTasks);
    TDTodaysTask *task = [todaysTasks objectAtIndex:row];
    [cellView.textField setStringValue:task.taskName];

    return cellView;
}
```

produces a log with

```
2014-06-19 16:59:35.211 Today[4513:303] (
    Test,
    Test,
    New
)
2014-06-19 16:59:35.212 Today[4513:303] (
    Test,
    Test,
    New
)
2014-06-19 16:59:35.214 Today[4513:303] (
    Test,
    Test //"New" somehow disappears for no reason
)
2014-06-19 16:59:35.215 Today[4513:303] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
```

when I use `addTask:` which makes no sense to me as I have not used `removeObjectAtIndex:` at all throughout my project. If I try add 2 objects instead in `addTask:` the previous 2 NSLogs produces the right output however the last one still outputs only the 2 results. A more detailed analysis of the memory address shows the last log has a much more different memory address than the previous logs, which is shown below.

```
2014-06-19 17:07:11.205 Today[4590:303] 0x60800024b5b0
2014-06-19 17:07:11.205 Today[4590:303] 0x60800024b5b0
2014-06-19 17:07:11.207 Today[4590:303] 0x60800024a260 //Address changes but I have not changed the array at all
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening so if anyone has any idea why this is happening that would be great.

Comment: Show your implementation of `numberOfRowsInTableView:`.

Comment: I suspect the issue is the use of the constant `NSString *task = @"New";`.  Try: `NSString *task = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"New"];` and tell me if there is a difference.

Comment: @trojanfoe Added it to the code above. The bizarre thing is that it shows there are 3 items in the array after I added the object, but when it asks for the last item in the table view NSLog tells me there's only 2 items

Comment: @trojanfoe Nope the problem still persists.

Comment: To me your code looks right so far, I'd say that the problem is that you're resetting the array in another place, maybe is it exposed as a property and someone is changing it?. Definitely, the problem is not in the code you've posted here.

Comment: @Carlos I've made my array a private instance variable and the problem still persists. In fact even when I create a new array that does the exact same thing (but should not be referenced elsewhere) both of them show the same problem where they both end up with 2 items in the last iteration instead of 3.

Comment: The it is within the code of that controller that you're creating the new nsmutablearray (different memory addresses spot it). Or maybe you're somehow creating a new controller and that's why memory address changed? If none of them, I'd suggest to share a link with the code and I can review it if you want to.

Comment: @Carlos So that's why! `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` calls awakeFromNib a couple times which causes my variables to reset, thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll mark you as correct :)

Comment: Cool! Posting it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably within the code of that controller that you're creating the new nsmutablearray (different memory addresses spot it).

Or maybe you're somehow creating a new controller and that's why memory address changed?

Comment: ["Calling makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: causes awakeFromNib to be called multiple times in your app. This is because makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: loads a NIB with the passed-in owner, and the owner also receives an awakeFromNib call, even though it’s already awake."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html)

Comment: lol let that be a lesson for me to stop abusing `awakeFromNib`

Comment: viewDidLoad sounds like the way to go

Comment: Or maybe initialize variables in init methods... :p